# "Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\category because the name is already in use"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

"Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\category because the name is already in use". How to fix it please someone explain me

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\category;
class category extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('admin.category.category_entry');
    }

    public function save(Request $request){
        $categoryentry=new category();
        $categoryentry->name=$request->name;
        $categoryentry->description=$request-> description;
        $categoryentry->publication_status=$request->publication_status;
        $categoryentry->save();
        return redirect('/category/save')->with('msg','Data inserted');
    }
}
```

Comment: should be CategoryController no Category so you don't have a model class and a controller class with same name

Comment: The Model name and Controller name must be different..Why you use similar name for both..It's making ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You controller class `category` is getting a name conflict with your model class `category`. 
Change your controller to **CategoryController**, it should fix the issue, also class name should always start with uppercase.

You can declare classes with same name in different namespaces but then you can't call the class into another class with same name, it'll cause a name conflict. So, your error is poping up because of the following:-

```
use App\category; 
class category extends Controller
```

you'll need to change the name of either one of them.

Comment: Surely they are in a seperate namespace?  It’s probably just a cooy past error where you have the wrong namespace...  there is no reason why he can’t name both model and controller just ‘category’ as long as they are in separate namespaces...

Comment: Yes surerly, he can but he can't do this `use App\category; class category extends Controller`. ;

Comment: i had this problem and not solved by composer dump-autoload then use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385832/308578

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used 2 class named `category` in this file. `App\category` and `App\Http\Controllers\category`.

you have 2 options to fix this:

1. resolve name conflict by changing the class names. for example
   change `App\Http\Controllers\category` to
   `App\Http\Controllers\categoryController`
2. rename the imported `App\category` to something else that doesn't exits in this file like this:

```
use App\category as categoryModel;

// ...


public function save(Request $request){

    $categoryentry=new categoryModel();

    // ...
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use this code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\category AS category_model;
class category extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('admin.category.category_entry');
    }

    public function save(Request $request){
        $categoryentry= new category_model;
        $categoryentry->name=$request->name;
        $categoryentry->description=$request->description;
        $categoryentry->publication_status=$request->publication_status;
        $categoryentry->save();
        return redirect('/category/save')->with('msg','Data inserted');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.